# Using a nonce Content Security Policy header for style-src for inline style elements returns errors

Tags: headers, nonce

When using a nonce in a Content Security Policy header, both Google Chrome and Firefox return errors. The nonce value is for a style element i.e. `<style id="some-id">// CSS </style>`

For example `Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' 'nonce-random-value'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-specific-hash'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.`

The nonce value is also present for scripts e.g.  //Javascript  which functions as intended.

The headers for these are;

```
"style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com 'nonce-".tu_custom_nonce_value () ."';".
"script-src 'self' https://maps.googleapis.com https://www.googletagmanager.com https://ajax.googleapis.com https://ajax.cloudflare.com https://static.cloudflareinsights.com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com 'nonce-".tu_custom_nonce_value () ."';";
```

According to the documentation from Mozilla - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/style-src, specifying a nonce for style-src is sufficient.

The only workaround currently is to specify a SHA256 hash for each element which is less than ideal since a change requires a manual step in the process each time WordPress is updated for example.

Any guidance or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you added the nonce to the `script-src` directive but not to the `style-src` directive. This might be the reason that why scripts are working but styles are not.

Possible solution:

```
"style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com 'nonce-".tu_custom_nonce_value () ."';".
"script-src 'self' https://maps.googleapis.com https://www.googletagmanager.com https://ajax.googleapis.com https://ajax.cloudflare.com https://static.cloudflareinsights.com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com 'nonce-".tu_custom_nonce_value () ."';";
```

Comment: Thanks Barry. The post has been updated. The nonce attribute has been added to the style element. The error continues to be displayed. In tracing the issue it appears that additional directives are generated that the nonce is not be added to. I'll accept the answer.